# Image orientation

Tags: 8, media

I try to fit portrait and landscape images to one size for Drupal 8. When I set image style (scale and crop 280x220) portrait images are automatically rotated. Then I tried to install Image effects module, but there is not choice Aspect switcher like in ImageCache Actions module for older Drupal. Do you know how to do it? Thank you.

Comment: When my Image style definition is without any effect the image is only rotated. It's very strange.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Strange, but it should all work with this module. On this page you can read about this module http://janezurevc.name/image-effects-module-for-drupal-8

Comment: I installed this module. I tried it, but I couldn't find any way how to do it. Image always is rotated when I scale portrait image.

Comment: Fixed, I added Automatically correct orientation from Image effect to my image styles but it was necessary to enable php Exif module.